# Android MediaCodec eglSwapBuffer blocking GPU in asynchronous mode

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have an video effect application where I am using OpenGL to draw to a frame buffer object, then drawing the resulting texture to the display, and then the MediaCodec input surface if the app is encoding.

I had initially written the encoder for API 18 in synchronous mode (based off of the big flake examples). I recently switched it to API 21 and asynchronous mode.

It records video fine, and I believe I have everything set up correctly. Howeverit seems the call to eglSwapBuffers causes the frame rate to drop significantly.

If I remove all other OpenGL calls it runs better, but what I'm rendering isn't that expensive (it can render fine multiple times per frame). Changing the encoder settings (i.e. from 640x360 @ 2Mbps to 1920x1080 @ 16Mbps) makes virtually no difference.

The only thing that makes it run faster is removing the call to eglSwapBuffers (which sends the buffer data to the encoder).

My understanding is that the output buffer does not block the call in asynchronous mode like it did before. Am I wrong about this? Is there a preferred way to call the renderer, or a method of rendering on a separate thread asynchronously?

Any help or ideas of where to start would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: which was the solution finally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in asynchronous mode, the output buffers still block the encoder - you need to process the output quickly and return the output buffers to the encoder after the asynchronous encoder output callback is called, otherwise you will end up blocking the input just as before.

The only difference between synchronous and asynchronous mode is that you don't need to poll for these events, but you get callbacks instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! That definitely answers one of my questions. In that case does it ever make sense to encode video asynchronously? Even if I immediately release the buffers on callback, and don't do anything else with the data, the render thread is still being blocked by eglSwapBuffers. Going back to synchronous mode and "draining" the encoder by releasing any output buffers I'm getting the same slowdown.

Comment: In general, yes, the asynchronous mode absolutely makes sense. As an example, think of an encoder that doesn't use the surface input mode, but plain buffers. At any given point, you need to wait for either a new free input buffer to use, or an output buffer to be filled. If you check for both of them with a zero timeout, you'll get the best throughput, but you'll basically end up busy looping. If you wait with a nonzero timeout, you'll avoid busy looping, but e.g. if you've filled all input buffers, you won't get any new input buffer until you wait for an output buffer and return it.

Comment: That is, in the synchronous mode, you've always got the tradeoff for how long to wait for inputs and outputs, to balance throughput vs busylooping. With asynchronous mode, just keep feeding inputs as much as possible, and drain the output when it is available. What you're seeing probably is that eglSwapBuffers waits for the encoder to provide a free input buffer to draw into, i.e. it's blocked by the speed the GL pipeline and video encoder are able to encode. The swap itself doesn't probably take that much time, but if there are no more free input buffers, it needs to wait for one.

Comment: Okay cool. So zero-ing the timeout in synchronous mode has no impact. Synchronous vs asynchronous mode has no impact. Changing the quality of the encoder has no impact, and neither does changing the codec type. So the problem is that I'm rendering too much for hardware to efficiently run the encoder as well? I guess the only thing I can do is render less (for this device anyway). Thanks for all of the help, you're doing a great job answering everyone's MediaCodec questions!